# Isomorphism in Exercise 2.17(d) of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, graded-rings

Let $R$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring, $P$ a homogeneous prime ideal of $R$, and $U$ the multiplicative subset $R \setminus P$. Let $R_{(P)}$ be the degree $0$ component of $R_P$, and let $f$ be an element of degree $1$ in $R$ that is not contained in $P$. Let $Q$ be the image of $P$ in the quotient $R / (f - 1)$. I have shown the following:

1. $Q$ is a prime ideal of $R / (f - 1)$.
2. $R_{(f)}$ (the degree $0$ component of $R_f$) is isomorphic to $R / (f - 1)$.
3. $(R_{(P)})[x, x^{-1}] \cong R_P$.

I need to show that $R_{(P)} \cong (R / (f - 1))_Q$. I think this should somehow follow by combining the previous results, but I just can't see it. Can anyone help here?

Comment: Are you able to finish using this [prior post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4019218/242) and/or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151592/242) on the same exercise?

Comment: I've taken a look at both of those - the first only deals with showing that $R / (f - 1) \cong R_{(f)}$ and the second with showing that $Q$ is prime. Maybe I just don't see how the same techniques apply in this case, but I haven't been able to figure out this last piece from those parts...